# include directories in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a big project with cmake as build system(sorry for my english)... I have directories with files:

```
directory1:
    |  CMakeLists.txt
    |  directory2:
    |      |   CMakeLists.txt
    |      |    file1.h
    |      |    file1.cpp
    |    file2.h
    |    file2.cpp
    |    file3.h
    |    file3.cpp
```

in upper cmake file we have:

```
set(TARGET target)
add_executable(${TARGET}
               directory2/file1.cpp
               file2.cpp
               file3.cpp
)
```

in lower cmake file we have:

```
include_directories(../)
```

at now in file1.cpp we include files as below:

```
 #include "file1.h"
 #include "../file2.h"
 #include "../file3.h"
```

what can I doing in cmake file for that we can include headers files in file1.cpp as below:

```
 #include "file1.h"
 #include "file2.h"
 #include "file3.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just add to upper cmake file:

```
include_directories(./)
```

Comment: Invocation of command `include_directories` in *lower* `CMakeLists.txt` **doesn't affect on upper** `CMakeLists.txt`, which actually compiles the source file (with `add_executable)`. It looks like the code you show us misses some meaningfull parts... (Like calling `add_executable()` from lower `CMakeLists.txt` too).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, i mad a mistake in answer: i add it in UPPER cmake file... fix